Flutter stepper connector is breaking for active step (3.27.1)?
I just update my flutter to latest version 3.27.1
I am seeing that connector is breaking for active step. See the image

Here is my code-
Stepper(
              elevation: 0,
              currentStep: value.currentIndex,
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              controlsBuilder: (context, details) => const Row(children: []),
              stepIconMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              connectorColor:
                  WidgetStateProperty.all<Color>(AppColors.primaryText),
              connectorThickness: 1,
              stepIconBuilder: (stepIndex, stepState) {
                if (stepIndex == value.currentIndex) {
                  return CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor:
                        AppColors.adaptiveColor(state.data!.fitnessLevel),
                    child: const Text(''),
                  );
                } else if (stepIndex < value.currentIndex) {
                  return CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor:
                        AppColors.adaptiveColor(state.data!.fitnessLevel),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.check,
                      size: 15,
                      color: AppColors.whiteBackground,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.primaryText,
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      AppVectors.lockIcon,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              steps: [
                Step(title: Text('Step1'), content: Text('Step Content 1')),
                Step(title: Text('Step2'), content: Text('Step Content 1')),
                Step(title: Text('Step3'), content: Text('Step Content 1'))
              ],
            )

What is changed on latest version API? I mean how can I back the connector again.
